# Getting duplicated row's in my MySQL View

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a view to output all posts by a users friends. The problem is that I get duplicated output of the posts. As you can see below in the view i get 2 rows with the same post. Is there a way to group the columns user1 and user2 with a posts like this

```
post   
  user1 user2   
  user1 user2
```

and not like its currently are doing

```
post user1 user2
post user1 user2
```

Underneath is my table structure

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                     posts                    | 
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+
| id | post | postBy | postTo | date | deleted |
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+
| 1  | text | 1      | 0      | date | 0       |
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+

+---------------------------+
|          friends          |
+----+-------+-------+------+
| id | user1 | user2 | date |
+----+-------+-------+------+
| 1  | 1     | 2     | date |
| 2  | 1     | 3     | date |
+----+-------+-------+------+

CREATE VIEW posts_by_friend AS SELECT posts.id, posts.post, posts.postBy, posts.postTo, posts.date, posts.deleted, friends.user1, friends.user2 FROM posts 
INNER JOIN friends ON (posts.postBy = friends.user1 OR posts.postBy = friends.user2) GROUP BY posts.id, friends.user1, friends.user2

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       posts_by_friend                        | 
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+-------+-------+
| id | post | postBy | postTo | date | deleted | user1 | user2 |
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+-------|-------|
| 1  | text | 1      | 0      | date | 0       | 1     | 2     |
| 1  | text | 1      | 0      | date | 0       | 1     | 3     |
+----+------+--------+--------+------+---------+-------+-------+

$userId = 1;

SELECT * FROM `posts_by_friend` WHERE `deleted`=0 AND (`user1`='$userId' or `user2`='$userId'));
```

Comment: You didn't add expected output table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the expected output (distinct posts) by applying `group_concat` on user1 and user2

```
CREATE VIEW posts_by_friend AS 
SELECT p.id, p.post, p.postBy, p.postTo, p.date, p.deleted, group_concat(f.user1) user1, group_concat(f.user2) user2 
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN friends f ON (p.postBy = f.user1 OR p.postBy = f.user2) 
GROUP BY  p.id, p.post, p.postBy, p.postTo, p.date, p.deleted
```